# SQL - SELECT statement with sub queries

Tags: sql, subquery, oracle10g

Lets take below table as sample

```
ID Name Status
1  Jon  pass
2  Jon  fail
3  Jon  fail
4  Snow pass
5  Snow fail
6  Snow fail
```

I need to write a query that displays results in the below format

```
Name Total Pass Fail
Jon  3     1    2
Snow 3     1    2
```

I am trying the following query with subquery in select but I know its not correct. Please advise.

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    count(ID) as Total,
    (SELECT count(ID) FROM results WHERE status = 'pass') as Pass
    (SELECT count(ID) FROM results WHERE status = 'fail') as Fail
FROM results
HAVING count(ID)>2 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY count(ID) desc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    COUNT(ID) as Total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'pass' THEN 1 END) Pass,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'fail' THEN 1 END) Fail
FROM results
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 2
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) desc;
```

I kept the `HAVING` clause (which must be placed after `GROUP BY`) because you use it in your code.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6307c6c6743fbebdf21fd02fc0af6061).
Results:

```
> NAME | TOTAL | PASS | FAIL
> :--- | ----: | ---: | ---:
> Jon  |     3 |    1 |    2
> Snow |     3 |    1 |    2
```

Comment: Great. New to conditional aggregations, can you please explain how it works?

Comment: `CASE WHEN status = 'pass' THEN 1 END` returns 1 only if `status = 'pass'` and only in this case the row is counted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below script-

```
SELECT 
Name, 
count(ID) as Total,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as Pass,
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as fail
FROM results
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING count(ID)>2 
ORDER BY count(ID) desc;
```